# processing by create instead of update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when I attempt to run my code, I got the error above.
I try to add specific attributes to my products, but every time I try to add them to my product, a new one is created instead of just edit the old.

Here is the result :

```
Started POST "/my_products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-03 16:33:46 +0100
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [a6533ae8-475f-4e] Processing by MyProductsController#create as JS
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [a6533ae8-475f-4e]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "my_product"=>{"size_name"=>"Gros oeuf", "size_img"=>"big-egg.png", "size_price"=>"40"}, "commit"=>"Choisir"}
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [a6533ae8-475f-4e]    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [a6533ae8-475f-4e]   SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `my_products` (`size_name`, `size_price`, `size_img`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Gros oeuf', '40', 'big-egg.png', '2016-01-03 15:33:46', '2016-01-03 15:33:46')
[localhost] [127.0.0.1] [a6533ae8-475f-4e]    (2.0ms)  COMMIT
```

My application_controller.rb :

```
def current_product
  if !session[:my_product_id].nil?
      MyProduct.find(session[:my_product_id])
  else
      MyProduct.new
  end
end
```

My Products_controller :

```
def base
    @myproduct = current_product
    @size = Size.all
    @chocolate = MyProductItem.where(item_category_id: 1)
end 

def create
    @myproduct = current_product
    if @myproduct.update(my_product_params)
        redirect_to(:back)
    else
        render 'new'
    end 
end
```

My base.html.erb :

```
<% @size.each do |size| %>
<div class="Box" >
    <p><%= size.name %></p>
    <p><%= image_tag size.image, style: 'width:7em;height:auto;' %></p>
    <p><%= number_to_currency size.price %></p>
    <p><%= size.description.try(:html_safe) %></p>
    <%= form_for @myproduct, remote: true do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :size_name, value: size.name %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :size_img, value: size.image %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :size_price, value: size.price %>
        <%= f.submit "Choisir", class: "addtocart", :id => "#orders" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

My models :

```
class MyProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :slug, :price, :image, :my_product_item_id, :user_id, :size_name, :size_img, :size_price
  has_many :elements, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :size, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :order

class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :price, :weight, :image, :description, :object_size
  belongs_to :my_product 
end
```

Any idea ?

Comment: my guess is `session[:my_product_id]` is not present, you need to debug this, add a print in the `current_product` method to check all the key, value pairs session has.

Comment: I did "<%= session.inspect %>" but there are so much informations, is there a cleaner way ?

Comment: I think @Mareq answered your question.

Comment: p.s. I would suggest to use f.hidden_field

`<%= f.hidden_field :id %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add field with proper `:my_product_id` value into the form:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:my_product_id, @my_product.id) if @my_product %>
```

If you invoke `base` action with `GET` request without parameters new object will be created, for update you must pass to this action parameter `my_product_id=value` (`value` is an `id` of updated product).

Comment: It do not work : "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Thanks, but I got the same error : "Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "my_product"=>{"my_product_id"=>""